# How to get libcrypto.lib and libcrypto.inc from OpenSSL source building?

Tags: build, openssl, nmake

I want to use library files of OpenSSL such as libcrypto.lib, libcrypto.inc, libssl.lib, libssl.inc and so on.
I built the OpenSSL source like this.

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32
nmake
nmake install
```

But I could get only some lib files from built result (C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL\lib)
How can I get *.inc files with *.lib files from build source of OpenSSL? For example, I want to get the library files like this for latest version of OpenSSL.

> https://github.com/mrfearless/libraries/tree/master/OpenSSL